# can't use .val on element found by .find

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a dynamically generated table, with (currently) a set rule that the first column has to be an unique identifier of some sort. The table is generated based on a json file, altought i don't think that's really important here.

Each table row has a anchor tag added with `class="delete"`. when i click that anchor tag, i execute the following code:

```
e.preventDefault();
var idCell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[0];
```

If i `console.log(idCell)`,i get `<td>01</td>` in my console.
If i `console.log(typeof idCell)` i get `object`.
If i console.log the type of a random element from the DOM, i get `object` as well.

My issue is: I cannot get the `.val()` from `idCell`, while i can access the `.val()` from any element directly filtered from the DOM.

My primary concern is why this is(n't) happening, and if there is a fix existing for this type of problem, i would be most gratefull if you would share it with me.

**EDIT 1:**
Here you have an example table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            id
        </th>
        <th>
            delete
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            01
        </td>
        <th>
            <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

please try to get me the ID of the table, when i click on the delete link, preferably using jQuery.

Comment: `.val` is for inputs, perhaps you need `.text`?

Comment: because [0] is DOM

Comment: and using `[0]` converts it to the raw dom element.

Comment: `.text` returns `undefined`. if `[0]` is DOM, then .val() should work, unless i don't really understand what you mean?

Comment: `.val()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method. It works only on jQuery objects. `[0]` picks a DOM object, so it doesn't work there. Use `.eq(0)` instead of `[0]`.

Comment: @JJJ your method returns nothing at all, and @Antal Gyuri your solution returns undefined. i also tried transforming `idCell` to a jQuery object by doing `$(idCell)`, but that doesn't help either

Comment: because you want to get a value of a `td` but it has no one, it has however an `innerHTML` property || `var contents = idCell.innerHTML`

Comment: @Antal Gyuri once again: `undefined`

Comment: Only input fields have values, table cells do not. It works fine with `.text()`: https://jsfiddle.net/o6mt2f16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [JJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/jjj) and 
[Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white)  mentioned, The solution is:

1) To use `.eq(0)` instead of `[0]` to keep the selector a jQuery element.

2) To use `.text()` instead of `.val()` since only input fields have values, and table cells don't.

Answer (score 0):

here's the script (works fine by me)

```
$(".delete").bind("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idCell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
    idCell.html("");
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault();